# Why did Jeremy Bentham call the english law a "Demon of Chicane"?

Tags: ethics

I'm wondering why Bentham called the old english law a "Demon of Chicane". Is it because the law preferred rich people over poor people?

Comment: NO: see [Jeremy Bentham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Bentham) : because of the complexity of the English legal code, which he termed the ["Demon of Chicane"](https://books.google.it/books?id=cH1ZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is mostly about obscure vocabulary.  (It is a better fit for English Language and Usage, where it will be seen by more people familiar with the language of Bentham's time.)

Comment: It would be useful to give a short extract showing where Bentham used this phrase; and in what context.

Comment: Chicane probably stands for chicanary, ie tricksy and unprincipled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Chicane' is an aspect of a racecourse or (perhaps its only remaining use) a golf course that is idiosyncratic to it, and the accommodation of which is about local knowledge or luck, not related to the overall quality or the more general skills of the competitors.

(In particular, *a chicane* is a place where a road has purposely injected narrow turns that cannot be seen very far ahead of time.

In Europe (or in New England) these can be logical, e.g. for traffic control, or to protect historical features.  In the newer parts of the New World they are more often attempts by surveyors to follow a line of longitude and a city grid structure at the same time, with no general rule as to when exactly to adjust the block size to synchronize these two competing goals.)

The nature of Common Law, is that it derives from history, agreements and argumentation as contrasted with other forms of law that would be known to Bentham, such as continental Civil Law, which derives from principles stated in a constitution; Uniform Military Law, which derives from a clear focus on efficiency and completeness in decision making; or even Church Law which has an ultimate unchanging anchor in scripture so that interpretation can only vary back and forth within fairly narrow bounds.

Compared to those, then, Common Law systems contain a great quantity of internal structure that is only very vaguely related to any logical structure, since it has simply evolved over time without any anchor other than the agreements among the nobility, the decisions of governing bodies, the trends of individual jurists, and other cultural conventions.

To someone of a modern scientific bent, who would prefer things be based on general principles and deduced from logical aspects, this is metaphorically the same kind of local, arbitrary unfairness that a racecourse or golf course riddled with an unexpected lack of uniformity presents.

So it is not so much about favoring the rich as about favoring the local, those with long or voluminous memories, the charismatic who persuade via sophistry and those with time to spend ferreting out idiosyncracies. This includes many varieties of the wealthy but excludes others, for instance, businessmen with times to market, and foreigners in general, especially the operators of complex international concerns.

(Sorry to be wordy, I often find such details more fascinating than they are due.)

Comment: Your use of the word is rather new, see http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chicane and https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/chicane, where the second definition of the french noun is the original meaning of the word. In the original meaning it is mainly a (possibly even rather unnecessary or inappropriate, that's what Bentham was definiely thinking about!) mean to delay, hinder or even avert a certain outcome. The road chicane is a chicane because it is a mean to force a slow down. It is a derivative use, as well as in golf. In Bentham's times, only the meaning I expressed was used.